# What is advantage of using modules as ssh2 or control over exec command from local shell?

Tags: node.js

How to execute specific command (for example ls -al) on remote and fetch result success or failure in Node.js ?
What is advantage of using modules as ssh2 or control over exec command from local shell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules like ssh2 will provide these functions even if ssh is not installed on the computer. Maybe they'll also be faster and lower on memory because they run in the same process, although I'm not sure of it.

Anyway, running exec('ssh') is fine. If it works for you, there is no reason to change it.